# How do I fix a violation of primary key constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I am restored the AdventureworksDW2012 and am trying to create a fact table in a new database tat I have created with Adventureworks being my source. When I run the following script, I get an error that says there is a violation of primary key:

I have tried using the DISTINCT function, but that is not working

```
INSERT INTO dbo.InternetSales
(SalesOrderNumber, ProductKey, DateKey,
OrderQuantity, SalesAmount,
UnitPrice, DiscountAmount, PromotionKey)
SELECT DISTINCT SalesOrderNumber as SalesOrderNumber,
ProductKey, OrderDateKey as DateKey,
OrderQuantity, SalesAmount,
UnitPrice, DiscountAmount, PromotionKey
FROM AdventureWorksDW2012.dbo.FactInternetSales
;
GO
```

I would like to be able to create the FactInternetSales table found in AdventureWorks in my new database

Comment: Add your table creation script for `InternetSales`

Comment: What is your primary key? My guess is you are trying to insert duplicate values for the primary key.

Comment: Right click on the table > script table as > create to....

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned which are the primary key columns.

Please make a composite primary key with the three columns (SalesOrderNumber, ProductKey, DateKey) or the four columns (SalesOrderNumber, ProductKey, DateKey,PromotionKey) for your [dbo][InternetSales] table. The primary key columns should be decided based on the data and business rules you are working with. 
This should resolve the possible duplicates.